# How overwrite the draw of menu item arrow of a TPopupMenu in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, frontend, draw, vcl, popupmenu

I am designing a popmenu and am using `TPopupMenu` component. Using the `Ownerdraw` property as `True` and implementing the `Ondraw` Item event I was able to do almost everything I wanted except override the arrow that shows item has subitems. I would like to know how to override the drawing of it, since it always appears, even using the `FillRect` method on the canvas of the menu item.

This is the menu currently:

[image: native arrow]

I wish you could do that

[image: my wish]

Comment: I do not understand how the answer to the other question can be implemented using Delphi with Pascal

Comment: You can pass your canvas'  handle to ExcludeClipRect,